# Specflow Living Doc - TestExecution.json file is not updating when using "dotnet test" or "vstest.console"

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, nunit, specflow, dotnet-test

So I've been trying to implement a script to run the tests in my suite and then run the LivingDoc generate command, this is all fine except for some reason when I run the tests via "dotnet test" or "vstest.console" the TestExecution.json is not being updated with the results, the update is only happening when I run them via test explorer in VS.

Am I missing a step somewhere I couldn't find anything in the doc, here is my script that I am running:

```
>     $scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
>     $dir = Split-Path $scriptpath
>     
>     dotnet test --filter TestCategory=Smoke
>     
>     Set-Location "$dir\bin\Debug\net6.0"
>     livingdoc test-assembly Specflow.Actions.Framework.dll -t TestExecution.json
>     Set-Location $dir
```

The rest of my suite is pretty basic, I am using Nunit with Specflow and Specflow.actions.selenium for my browser interactions.

Comment: in which folder are you executing this script?

Comment: Hey Andreas, sorry it's sorted now re-installed the package and it started working, for clarity though I was running dotnet test and vstest.console from the correct directories, the livingDoc command is being run from the "{project}\bin\Debug\net6.0" folder where the project dll is and where the "TestExecution.json" is.